# All processes have my_rank = 0, how to fix?

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I have a problem concerning running mpi programs. All processes claims that their rank is 0.

I have searched a lot around, and found out that this is caused by communication between the openMP version and something else, and that I have to check which mpi I invoke. But no one explains properly, in a way that works, how to fix this.

1. Do I have to uninstall something? In that case, what should I uninstall and how do I do it?
2. Do I have to install something? What and how?
3. If the answer is no to the previous questions, how can I then fix it?
4. How could this problem occur as I only did what my lecturer told me, I think?

Comment: Is there a programing question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Many users can help you here, but your question must be specific to a programming issue. Please follow these guidelines to make the task easier for them. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is this openMP or Open MPI ?

Comment: I use Open MPI for this program

Answer (score 1):

This typically occurs when you are mixing two MPI libraries.

For example, you are using `mpirun` from `MPICH` but your app is using the libraries from `Open MPI`.

You should first double check that, for example

```
$ which mpirun
$ mpirun -np 1 ldd a.out
```

both should point to the same directory (e.g. same vendor **and** version)

Comment: First output:
/usr/bin/mpirun                                                                                 

Second output:
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x...)
libmpich.so.12 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpich.so.12 (0x...)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x...)
libcr.so.0 => /usr/lib/libcr.so.0 (0x...)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x...)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x...)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x...)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x...)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x...)

Comment: I am sorry about the last comment, but SO wouldn't let me split it in nice paragraphs. And I posted it in order to hear if anyone reads anything out of it. As I do not know enough to understand what I should look for

Comment: Your app is clearly using `MPICH` library, so assuming `mpirun` is provided by Open MPI, that cannot work. You can either rebuild your app with Open MPI, or use MPICH’s mpirun.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should edit your question with this kind of new information (so you can format it) and drop a comment so notifications are sent.